# Where can I find/unbind control shift space? (^⇧ + space)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, system-settings, keybindings

I read through all of the system-wide keyboard shortcuts in "System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts" and I could not find nor unbind the Control+Shift+Space macro for use by [SkipTune's](http://skiptunes.com/) pause/play keybinding. I know how to bind it in SkipTunes, but it just shows me this:[image: Skip Tunes Error]

Comment: (^⇧ + space) works for me in iTunes. You might have a look through your login items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macs containing a trackpad (i.e. MacBooks) or with a trackpad attached allow *Chinese Trackpad Handwriting*. The shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> shows and hides this trackpad.

[image]

I have no clue what I have written.

To disable it [enable](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22639?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) Chinese Trackpad Handwriting and then disable/remove the shortcut for *Show/Hide Trackpad Handwriting* in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Keyboard.

Comment: Interesting, but I still don't know where the setting to disable the keybinding is.

Comment: @JeffM Added description how to disable it.